# how to use the variable as its original value which is converted to string in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

It is a variable which is converted to string from of type date. However, i want to use it in WHERE selection by days.

```
SELECT t1, t2,CONVERT(varchar(10), mydate, 105) [mydate] FROM tableName
WHERE [mydate] BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd 
ORDER BY mydate //error
```

In above sql query, `@dateStart` and `@dateEnd` are of type string (somethings like "26/07/2016")in C#, but it is not important.

The problem is how to written a sql query that will return the mydate of type string, but will also do calculation in its date type.

[update 1]

my testing case.

```
startDayStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
 endDayStr =  DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "0101";

 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT t1, t2,CONVERT(varchar(10), mydate, 105) [mydate] FROM tableName
WHERE [mydate] BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd 
ORDER BY mydate //error", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateStart", startDayStr);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateEnd", endDayStr);
// not thing selected
```

Comment: Using aliases are not supported in the `where` clause. Just write it up again in the `order by`

Comment: i will replace the @dateStart as something like "28/01/2016"

Comment: @kingyau - can you add the error that you get?

Comment: I would advise to avoid changing dates into strings unless it is to display the date to a user.  If the user enters a date in a known date format, change that to a date as soon as possible.

Comment: Why do you use strings to pass date values to sql server in the first place? C#'s DateTime maps directly to Sql server DateTime, just pass the DateTime as is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1, t2,CONVERT(varchar(10), mydate, 105) [mydate] FROM tableName
    WHERE mydate BETWEEN cast(@dateStart as date) AND cast(@dateEnd as date) 
    ORDER BY mydate
```

Use the above query and pass `@dateStart` and `@dateEnd` in format 'yyyyMMdd'

use the below code to convert date to format 'yyyyMMdd'

```
 string datestart = DateTime.ParseExact(userDateInput, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: what is the type of [mydate] in the where part? date or varchar?

Comment: type is same as database column type i.e. date

Comment: how can i pass dateStart and dateEnd in format 'dd/MM/yyyy'? It is need because the dateStar is entered by user...

Comment: check modified answer. i have added code to output date in required format. convert both start date and end date and pass it to database. you need to pass date in format 'yyyyMMdd' not 'dd/MM/yyyy'

Comment: WOW, C# version..i only check the sql convert() ..yours is better :)

Comment: Oh,sorry, noting selected... :(

Comment: you startdate is greater than end date. it will always return nothing